# Measure average web app response time from the client side during a long period of time

Tags: performance

My company has over a hundred users of a specific CRM web application, which is provided as a service by another company to us.

The users of this application are very dissatisfied with its average response time, and I need to find a way to gather metrics during a certain period of time (let's say .. a week) to prove the service provider that they are really providing a bad service.

If the application were mine, I would get the metrics from New Relic or some other equivalent monitoring service, but since it is not, I'm looking for something that could do some sort of client side monitoring.

I already checked Page Speed from Google and YSlow from Yahoo, but both are only useful when you want to test the application during a few seconds. They are not meant for the long term monitoring I need.

Would anybody know a way to get this kind of monitoring from a client side perspective?

Answer (score 1):

[LoadRunner](http://www.pronq.com) is no charge for 50 users, but what you really need is not a test tool but a synthetic user monitor which runs every n number of minutes and pulls the stats.   You can build it yourself using LoadRunner 12, Jmeter, or any other http sampling technology.   You could also use a service like [Gomez](http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/user-experience-management/synthetic-web-and-mobile/overview.html) for sampling or [mpulse from SOASTA](http://www.soasta.com/products/mpulse/) for tracking every page component across all users.

Keep in mind that your developer tools will time all of the components of the request to give you some page times.   As will [Dynatrace](http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/user-experience-management/real-user-monitoring-web-and-mobile/overview.html) for the web client.

If you have access to the web server then consider configuring the web server logs to capture the [w3c time-taken field](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html), which will track every request.   Depending upon the server the level of granularity can be to the millionth of a second on each and every request.

You could also look at a service like [LiteSquare](http://www.litesquare.com) which can process those web logs and provide ammunition for changes to the server to improve performance on a no-gain, no-charge model.

Answer (score 0):

One (expensive) solution would be using **[LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/)** endurance test feature. Check **[here](http://easyloadrunner.blogspot.ro/2013/07/soak-tests-or-endurance-testing.html)** for a demonstration.

Another tool is [**Oracle OATS**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/etest-101273.html).

[**JMeter**](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a free tool, though I'm not sure if it's reliable enough to run for a whole week.

These are load generator tools, so if you are testing as a single client, you should carefully chose your load amount (e.g. one user).

Last but not least, you could create your own webservice client, and create a **[cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)** to run it on your specified time of day and log the access time.

---

If what you want is to **get data from their server**, this is impossible ... without hacking into it. All you can do is monitor the website as a client, using some of the above tools, make a report and present that to them. But even so they could challenge your bandwidth, your test method etc.

I recommend that you negotiate with them to give you their logs and to prove that their system can support a certain amount of load. If you are a customer to them, you can file a complain or test additional offers.

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but I wouldn't like to do a simulation. I wanted to monitor the behaviour of the remote system while my users actually use it. They access dozens of different pages and features all day long. Therefore, creating a simulation would take a very long time.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine that hosts the web application? If so, you can add monitoring tools on it

Comment: No, I don't. That's the source of all my problems. I need to prove to another company that their web application responds slowly, and I need to gather some concrete evidence. They won't just believe my word.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot prove that they are not allocating enough computing resources because you cannot login to their machine and you cannot get their logs. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace was already mentioned in combination with Load Testing. As you said that you want to monitor your live system I want to bring Dynatrace up again. Most of the time it is used to do live system monitoring to understand what end users are actually doing. It is also available as a 30 day trial - so - no need to buy it - but - use it for your sanity check: http://bit.ly/dttrial